# Embedding Schema.org structured data in PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, schema.org, structured-data

Is it possible to embed Schema.org markup (JSON-LD, Microdata, or RDFa) inside PDF documents?

Use case:
I generate PDF invoices, which I would like to import into accounting system. Structured data markup would help me with this.

Comment: What accounting system do you use? Do they advertise schema.org integration?

Comment: Use a file attachment

Comment: @Brad Our company makes both accounting and invoicing systems. I am researching the possibilities how to make imports easier. Since e-invoices became a trend and massively taking place of the paper ones customers usually exchange them via email. And if they are already electronic (a file) why should do OCR or difficult parsing - not to mention every SW has its own invoice template.

Comment: @Kevin Brown : How exactly?

Comment: Take a look at the German [ZUGFeRD standard for electronic invoicing](http://www.ferd-net.de/index.html?changelang=4). This is gaining popularity in Germany and also in the European Union. It combines a PDF/A-3 invoice document with a standardized XML invoice as an attachment. Maybe this helps you avoiding to reinvent the wheel.